# How to catch ConnectionException,UnknownHostException?

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch, unknown-host

I am calling server task and I want to catch all network related exceptions. I am getting the `java.net.ConnectException`. I am not getting from where its throw and where to catch.

Server class:

```
  public class ServerRequest {
    String api;
    JSONObject jsonParams;

    public ServerRequest(String api, JSONObject jsonParams) {
        this.api = api;
        this.jsonParams = jsonParams;
    }

    public JSONObject sendRequest(){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(api);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(jsonParams.toString());
            writer.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if  (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                Log.d("ServerResponse", new String(sb));
                return new JSONObject(new String(sb));
            } else {
                throw new UnexpectedServerException("Unexpected server exception with status code : "+responseCode);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(me);
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(ioe);
        } catch(UnexpectedServerException ue) {
            ue.printStackTrace();
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(ue);
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            je.printStackTrace();
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(je);
        }

    }

    public ServerRequest(String api) {
        this.api = api;
    }


    public JSONObject sendGetRequest() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(api);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoInput(true);

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if  (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                Log.d("ServerResponse", new String(sb));
                return new JSONObject(new String(sb));
            } else {
                throw new UnexpectedServerException("Unexpected server exception with status code : "+responseCode);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(me);
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(ioe);
        } catch(UnexpectedServerException ue) {
            ue.printStackTrace();
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(ue);
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            je.printStackTrace();
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(je);
        }
    }
}
```

And exceptions are these:

```
  java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to xesoftwares.co.in/104.131.162.126 (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:504)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext(SocketConnector.java:67)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.weberz.helper.ServerRequest.sendRequest(ServerRequest.java:37)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.weberz.AsyncTasks.UpdateTokenAsyncTask.doInBackground(UpdateTokenAsyncTask.java:44)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.weberz.AsyncTasks.UpdateTokenAsyncTask.doInBackground(UpdateTokenAsyncTask.java:17)
12-16 16:08:17.811 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
12-16 16:08:17.812 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-16 16:08:17.812 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
12-16 16:08:17.812 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
12-16 16:08:17.812 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
12-16 16:08:17.812 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-16 16:08:17.812 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
12-16 16:08:17.812 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
12-16 16:08:17.817 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
12-16 16:08:17.817 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
12-16 16:08:17.817 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
12-16 16:08:17.817 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     ... 24 more
12-16 16:08:17.822 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to xesoftwares.co.in/104.131.162.126 (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
12-16 16:08:17.822 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
12-16 16:08:17.822 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
12-16 16:08:17.822 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:504)
12-16 16:08:17.822 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
12-16 16:08:17.822 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext(SocketConnector.java:67)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.weberz.helper.ServerRequest.sendRequest(ServerRequest.java:37)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.weberz.Activities.MainActivity$GetUserAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:658)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.weberz.Activities.MainActivity$GetUserAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:622)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
12-16 16:08:17.823 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-16 16:08:17.824 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
12-16 16:08:17.825 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
12-16 16:08:17.825 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
12-16 16:08:17.825 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
12-16 16:08:17.825 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
12-16 16:08:17.825 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     ... 24 more
12-16 16:08:17.831 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "xesoftwares.co.in": No address associated with hostname
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:470)
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
12-16 16:08:17.832 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.weberz.helper.ServerRequest.sendRequest(ServerRequest.java:37)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.weberz.AsyncTasks.GetContactsAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetContactsAsyncTask.java:90)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at com.weberz.AsyncTasks.GetContactsAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetContactsAsyncTask.java:32)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
12-16 16:08:17.833 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
12-16 16:08:17.834 10957-11559/com.weberz W/System.err:     ... 22 more
```

How shall I catch all these exceptions of `UnknownHostException`, `java.net.ConnectionException`, `UnexpectedServerException`, `MalformedServerException`?

I tried to catch the exceptions in `postExecute` method after the `JSONException` but it shows the exception is not thrown here..

Please help. Thank you..

EDIT: I tried something like this to add a boolean variable and make it true when exception throws but not working.. Please check;

```
   public class GetContactsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    String api;
    String userId;
    JSONObject jsonParams;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    public JSONArray contactListArray;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ContactGetCallBack contactGetCallBack;
    private ContactAdapter adapter;
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS1 = "Success";
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private MainActivity activity;
    private ContactTableHelper contactDb;
    private Boolean exception = false;

    public GetContactsAsyncTask(ContactGetCallBack contactGetCallBack, Context context, String userId,MainActivity activity) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.contactGetCallBack=contactGetCallBack;
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    public interface ContactGetCallBack {
        void doPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList ) throws JSONException;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

        if(!isOnline())
        {
            activity.showAlert("Please check internet connection.");
        }
        else {

            // progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String...params) {
        try {
            api = ServiceUrl.getBaseUrl() + ServiceUrl.getContactsUrl();;
            jsonParams = new JSONObject();

            String user_id = this.userId;

            jsonParams.put("user_id", user_id); // params[0] is userid

            ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest(api, jsonParams);
            return request.sendRequest();

        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(je);
        }
        catch (Exception ue) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            activity.showAlert("Please check internet connection.");
            exception = true;
            return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(ue);
        }

    }  //end of doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);

        if (response.has("message"))
        {
            try {
                if( response.getString("message").equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SUCCESS1)){
                   // Toast.makeText(mContext,"success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     contactListArray = response.getJSONArray("contacts");

                    contactDb = new ContactTableHelper(mContext);

                    for (int i = 0; i < contactListArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject subObject1 = contactListArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Contact contact = new Contact();
                        JSONObject subObject = subObject1;
                        String contactName = subObject.getString("user_name");
                        //name of the attribute in response
                        String pass = subObject.getString("password");
                        String contactId = subObject.getString("user_id");
                        String contactMobile = subObject.getString("mobile_no");
                        String contactEmailId = subObject.getString("email_id");
                        String contactProfile = subObject.getString("profile_image");
                        String fullName = subObject.getString("full_name");
                        String jobTitle = subObject.getString("job_title");
                        String homeAddress = subObject.getString("home_address");
                        String workPhone = subObject.getString("work_phone");
                        String workAddress = subObject.getString("work_address");
                        String company = subObject.getString("company");

                        contact.setmThumbnail(contactProfile);
                        contact.setmUserName(contactName);
                        contact.setmMobileNo(contactMobile);
                        contact.setmEmailId(contactEmailId);
                        contact.setmProfileImage(contactProfile);
                        contact.setContactId(contactId);
                        contact.setmHomeAddress(homeAddress);
                        contact.setmFullName(fullName);
                        contact.setmJobTitle(jobTitle);
                        contact.setmWorkAddress(workAddress);
                        contact.setmWorkPhone(workPhone);
                        contact.setmPass(pass);
                        contact.setmCompany(company);

                        contactList.add(contact);//adding string to arraylist

                        contactDb.addContact(new Contact(contactId,contactName,pass,contactMobile,contactEmailId,contactProfile,fullName,jobTitle,workAddress,workPhone,homeAddress,company));

                        contactDb.close();
                    }
                    contactGetCallBack.doPostExecute(contactList);

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                else if(response.getString("message").equalsIgnoreCase("Contact list is empty")){

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    activity.showAlert("You do not have any contacts yet.");
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
               // progressDialog.dismiss();
            //   activity.showAlert("Please check internet connection.");

            }
           if(exception)
           {
               activity.showAlert("Please check internet connection.");
           }
        }
    }
    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
    //end of onPostExecute
}
```

Also I have Exception2Json class

```
   public class Excpetion2JSON {
    public static JSONObject getJSON(Exception e) {
    try{
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("result", -4);
        json.put("message", e.getMessage());
        return json;
    } catch(JSONException je) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

And UnexpectedServerException class:

```
public class UnexpectedServerException extends Exception {
    public UnexpectedServerException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added internet permission in manifest file

Comment: yes, i have added. @Pravin

Comment: Internet connection works, I want to catch the exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Your network call is started in the background (async mode), so you should use try catch in doInBackground and set a variable in GetContactsAsyncTask class that it will check in onPostExecute to returning appropriate value.
consider that onPostExecute will run on UiThread.

Comment: catch exception in doInBackground with a try catch block and set it to exception field of GetContactsAsyncTask class. After that you should check  exception class field in onPostExecute method by checking it like this:

if (exception instanceof MalformedServerException) {
    exception.getSomeCustomViolations();
} else if (exception instanceof java.net.ConnectionException) {
    exception.getSomeOtherCustomViolations();
} 
and ...

Comment: But if I try to catch UnnownKnownHost exception in doInbackground method it gives me error that this exception is not thrown here. Can you please show me a demo code

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html
use parent class of UnknownHostExceptionto catch. after use instanceof to check.

Comment: not getting it still. Please can you help me with code.

Answer (score 0):

Add those exceptions to your sendRequest method, either to your existing catch block or just change it `catch (Exception e)`.